# I want to replace all instances of {0} on a page with an image or run a function when that is printed out. can i do this with php?

Tags: php

I am making a widget that shows images in places where the user puts a {0} or {5}. can this be done with php? i dont know where to start and i have worn out my fingertips searching for it on google because i dont know good keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. For simple cases use [`str_replace`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and for more complex cases use [`preg_replace`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

The supplied PHP manual links will tell you all about it. You'll probably want to try `str_replace` first as it's much simpler than using regular expressions.

```
// replace all occurrences of "{0}" with "AWESOME"
$str = "{0} --- {0}";
$str = str_replace("{0}", "AWESOME", $str);
echo $str; // outputs: AWESOME --- AWESOME
```

Comment: this looks like it only replaces strings with strings, im looking for a image or script replacement for a string.

Comment: as long as it replaces it with other things, i looked at the php str_replace pages and it looked like it just replaced a string with a string. thx

Comment: so, you do this: `$str = str_replace("{0}", "<img src='image.jpg'>", $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Very simply use string replace:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$text = str_replace("[0]", "<im>", $text, $count);
```

Comment: this looks like it only replaces strings with strings, im looking for a image or script replacement for a string.